# Determining optimum area of parafoil, and then drag

Tags: wing, drag

I am designing a parafoil recovery system for a small payload of 300x100x500mm (2.4kg).

I have chosen an Aspect Ratio of 3, and from a NASA wind tunnel test report, the coefficient of lift and drag is 0.98 and 0.194 respectively. (L/D) is 5.05 and optimum angle of attack for the parafoil is 9degrees.

The parafoil should descend at a max vertical velocity of 7m/s.

I am struggling to work out what the optimum area of the parafoil should be for this.

I then need to workout the drag of the system and the flight path angle and velocity to model the trajectory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!